# handle jsonp with varnish

Tags: caching, jsonp, varnish, varnish-vcl

I try to configure varnish so it can handle jsonp.
I use as the basic concept this source: https://gist.github.com/640331

I'm using varnish 3.0.2 so I ended up [with this](https://gist.github.com/2643616/5f32653a9abc20b77eb225b37248351f791bb001)

After sending a request to the server:

```
curl http://example.com/test?callback=test
```

I get the following:

```
test(<esi:include src="http://example.com/test" />);
```

Insted of:

```
test({...cached-json...});
```

The syslog output:

```
The syslog outputs the following:
May 09 12:48:45 [varnishd] before if for: /JSONP-ESI-TEMPLATE
May 09 12:48:45 [varnishd] before if for: callback, url: example.com:6081
May 09 12:48:45 [varnishd] in if for: callback, url: example.com:6081
May 09 12:52:40 [varnishd] before if for: /JSONP-ESI-TEMPLATE
May 09 12:52:40 [varnishd] in if for: /JSONP-ESI-TEMPLATE
May 09 12:52:40 [varnishd] before if for: obj.status == 760
May 09 12:52:40 [varnishd] in if for: obj.status == 760
May 09 12:52:40 [varnishd] before if for: beresp.http.X-ESI
May 09 12:52:40 [varnishd] in if for: beresp.http.X-ESI
May 09 12:52:40 [varnishd] before if for: beresp.http.X-JSONP-Server
May 09 12:52:40 [varnishd] in if for: beresp.http.X-JSONP-Server
```

How to evaluate the esi request to get the json?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution!
[Looks like this](https://gist.github.com/4557315).

If You are using gzip for Your json responses, don't forget to enable gzip for jsonp:

```
if ( beresp.http.content-type ~ "application/javascript" ) { 
  set beresp.do_gzip = true;
}
```

Comment: The link appears broken, is there an updated example available?